Googleログイン時のエラー「現在、ファイルを開くことができません。アドレスを確認して、もう一度試してください」が特定アカウントのみ発生してしまう
Googleログイン時に以下のようなエラーメッセージが表示されてしまい、解決できずに困っているので助けてほしいです。
現在、WordPressで作成した会員制のWebサイトにおいて、ログイン画面にGoogleログインボタンを設置しており、そのGoogleログインを発火条件とした独自のGoogle Apps Scriptを構築している状況です。
Googleログイン時に以下の2つの分岐をする仕様にしています。
A. 特定の条件に一致するユーザー(会員登録済みユーザー)のみ、会員制のWebサイトのTOPページが表示される
B. 条件に一致しないユーザー(会員未登録ユーザー)については、「管理者に問い合わせてください」というエラー画面を表示させる。
Googleログインを実行した際に、上記のAかBかの2択しか表示されないと思っていたのですが、事前に準備していたエラー画面ではなく、Googleのエラー画面「現在、ファイルを開くことができません。アドレスを確認して、もう一度試してください」が表示されてしまい、そもそもGoogleログインができないという事象が発生しています。
検証をしていたところ、以下のような条件で起きることがわかっています。
検証してわかったこと

特定のアカウントでのみ発生
スマホ環境で発生
iOSではなくAndroidでのみ発生
ブラウザはChromeアプリを使用
キャッシュクリアやアプリのアンインストール、すべてのアカウントからログアウトなどを試行しても状況は変わらず
ログインできないアカウントは毎回必ず同じ
ログインできないエラーが発生すると、「アプリ情報 > ストレージ > データを消去 > すべてのデータを削除」をしないとログイン画面にアクセスできなくなる
1つのプロファイルに3つのアカウントでログインしており、1つはログイン成功、2つ目, 3つ目のアカウントはログインに失敗する
別のAndroid端末と別のGoogleアカウントで検証した結果、1つのプロファイルに3つのアカウントでログインしているという同じ環境化にも関わらず、その検証時ではすべてのアカウントでログインに成功した

今回解決したいこと

毎回エラーが起きている該当のアカウントでGoogleログインに成功するようにする
1つのプロファイルに複数のアカウントでログインしていても、すべてのアカウントでログインできるようにする

エラーメッセージ:

「現在、ファイルを開くことができません。アドレスを確認して、もう一度試してください」


